# Creating custom tk canvas widget

Tags: c++, canvas, tcl, tk-toolkit, xlib

I need to crate custom tk canvas widget (plot). How to do it is  described http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TkLib/CrtItemType.htm.

It is the dispay function which is called when canvas need to show plot.

```
void
PlotItem::DisplayPlot( Tk_Canvas canvas, Tk_Item *itemPtr, Display *display, Drawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    PlotItem *plotPtr = (PlotItem *) itemPtr;
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, drawable, 0, 0);
    XFillRectangle(display, drawable, gc, 100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 
    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    } 
    if (Tk_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    } 

    Tk_CreateItemType(&tkPlotType); 
    int result = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source main.tcl");

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << interp->result << '\n';

    Tk_MainLoop(); 
    return 0;
}
```

main.tcl

```
wm title . program_tk
wm minsize . 628 628

canvas .vp -background white -width 310 -height 224
canvas .hp -background white -width 310 -height 224

pack .vp 
pack .hp 

set verticalPlot [eval .vp create plot 1 1 ]
set horizontalPlot [eval .hp create plot 1 1 ]
```

It is created two different canvas widgets, both containing plot widget. Only code of display function is shown because other functions don't do anything. I only need simple functionality(display the plot). Instead of plot here is printing rectangle.
 The issue is that black rectangle is displayed only on the first plot, the second is empty. How this could happen ?

Comment: The code doesn't look too bad (you're missing a call to XFreeGC and should consider Tk's functions for GC management, but that's a side point) so I'm guessing the real issue is in the part that you've not shown us so far. Perhaps the bounding box calculations are off?

Comment: @DonalFellows It worked after adding bounding box calculations, thank you